# Is there a CSS selector for any field that the user types in?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to create some common styling for all elements where the user selects (either with a mouse or tapping on in a touch screen) and then inputs text with a cursor.  This includes:

- `<input>`
- `<input type='text'>`
- `<textarea>`
- `<input type='password'>`
- `<another element that I didn't know existed that you can type into>`

As you can see (and other examples probably), due to the `<textarea>` (which falls in this category) and `<input type='submit'>` (which doesn't) you can't just select all `<input>`'s.

Is there a special CSS (pseudo?) selector for this?

Comment: Does this include [`contenteditable`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable) regions?

Comment: Short answer is no, but bear in mind that for some input types, whether or not a user can input text with a cursor may depend on which browser they are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, there isn't.

Either you go with lists

```
input, textarea {...}
```

or you use a css-preprocessor (e.g. sass) and make yourself a mixin or a function that handles all these types. But you won't get around defining all these elements at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a css class:

```
<input class="user-input">
<input type='text' class="user-input">
<textarea class="user-input">
<input type='password' class="user-input">
```

And then you'd style based on that class. While this may not be as automatic as you desire, this provides you th most control and would allow you to avoid styling submit buttons for example.

You could also do the inverse, of course, and have a class "non-user-input" which then would be put on things like the submit button. Then you just target `<input>`, `<textarea>` and etc.

This might be more appropriate for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a field for this, but you can combine selectors with commas and style them all together like this:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="search"], input[type="password"], textarea {
  /* your styles here */
}
```

I think this is the only way to do it.

Comment: I didn't know there was a type="search", further demonstrating the value of a selector like this.

Comment: perhaps `input[type!="submit"], textarea` ?

Comment: @BrianGlaz - `type="image"` (and possibly others) is going to throw a wrench into the "not submit" works.

Comment: You could do this, but there are many different types of input that don't involve typing (like range, radio, etc.). The list is kind of long, but it's manageable: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the :focus pseudo-class in CSS all by itself to select any HTML element that is selected.

CSS:

```
:focus {
  /* whatever you want to do to all selected elements */
}
```

Here's a JS fiddle showing how it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/vbdgenwz/

Comment: This is true, but it's not what OP is asking. Also, focus applies to more than just things you can type into (like regular hyperlinks or anything with a tabindex).

Comment: ah yes, event a `<select>` field can be selected, right?  And this isn't about styling an element once it's selected.  It's about styling something that COULD be focused on and typed in to.

Comment: ahh sorry I guess I misunderstood the questions.